# How to make g_printer (USB-gadget printer) work in Orangepi Zero

Tags: debian

I'm trying to use gadget mode on a Orange Pi Zero and the g_printer device to emulate a printer so I can capture data, process it. I've set up the board using the link  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atCsc.png): https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_printer.txt. When i connect my device(Orangepi zero) to host(Linux) it detect as g_printer. But i cannot print anything with this. How to solve this? It creates /dev/g_printer0 on the gadget side and /dev/usb/lp0 on the host side. My dmesg at Opizero is [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example code in the link that you pasted with the `-read_data` flag, or use any way you like to read the file (/dev/g_printer0):  `more /dev/g_printer0`

After you've done this, just write something to /dev/usb/lp0 on the host side, again just a standard file.
Simplest would be to `echo "asdf" >> /dev/usb/lp0`

Take care of the permissions for both files, you need your user to be in the lp group and have write permissions.

Comment: yes i write to /dev/usb/lp0 .. i want to sent a pdf to print. how o sent it?

Comment: Have you tried setting up CUPS, lp, lpr, etc?